# How to "unpack" a vector variable into several variables?

Tags: matlab

In Python, a 3-tuple (for example) can be "unpacked" into three separate variables through assignment:

```
In [1]: triplet = (1, 'two', (True, True, True))

In [2]: first, second, third = triplet

In [3]: third
Out[3]: (True, True, True)

In [4]: second
Out[4]: 'two'

In [5]: first
Out[5]: 1
```

Is it possible to do something like this in MATLAB?

Everything I've tried fails.  E.g.:

```
>> triplet = {1, 'two', [true, true, true]};
>> [first second third] = triplet
Too many output arguments.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can rely on cell expansion using `{:}` indexing which creates a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which can be assigned to three output values.

```
[a, b, c] = triplet{:};
```

If `triplet` were a matrix instead, you could first convert it to a cell array using `num2cell`.

```
triplet = [1, 2, 3];
tripletcell = num2cell(triplet);

[a, b, c] = tripletcell{:};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I take it that `deal` is the more general of the two, because it would work even if `triplet` were, say, a `double(1, 3)`?

Comment: @kjo Not really,  you would have to provide each output as an input argument to `deal`. I have updated with an example using numeric arrays.