# Unpacking a vector into k variables

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I'm learning matlab and trying to implement [small angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) using vectorisation. This is the formula I'm trying to implement:

[image]

I'm implementing this for 3 angles: `pi / 100`, `pi / 10` and `pi / 6`. I've come up with this so far:

```
x = [pi / 100, pi / 10, pi / 6];
y = sin(x);
e = (y - x) ./ y;
```

This works fine. Now, I want to unpack the result into 3 variables. I know I can do this:

```
RelativeError100 = e(1);
RelativeError10 = e(2);
RelativeError6 = e(end);
```

But coming from a python background, this seems a bit clunky to me. So I tried this:

```
[RelativeError100, RelativeError10, RelativeError6] = e
```

Which errors out, giving `Too many output arguments.`. So, I did a little research, and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38190561/4909087) which suggests

```
[RelativeError100, RelativeError10, RelativeError6] = e{:}
```

Which throws a `Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`.

What am I missing, and how can I get this to work? Or is it just not possible with matlab?

Comment: I like to think that the reason why this is non-trivial is that going from an array to individual scalar variables is half way down to dynamic variable name land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about：

```
x = [pi / 100, pi / 10, pi / 6];
y = sin(x);
e = num2cell((y - x) ./ y);
[RelativeError100, RelativeError10, RelativeError6] = e{:}
```

It's since `{:}` only works when `e` is a `cell`, but not a `matrix`.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. I initially tried something like this: `[...] = numcell(e){:}` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: As far as I know, `num2cell` (but not 'numcell') is a MATLAB  function, and `function(){:}` might return an error due to an unknown index. :D

Comment: Sorry, meant `num2cell`. That was a typo. Thanks again :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah, some MATLAB users have been asking to index off of literals and function calls for a while now.  The MathWorks remains unwilling.